# how to display base64 and uri in react native image component

Tags: react-native

I have a component which picks the image from galllery and returns the uri of the file i'm using expo-image-picker for that. But since i'm using `data:image/jpg;base64,${imageUri}` this as the source value i'm not able to display image when i pass the uri value to it, I have a base64 value coming from server so is there any way i can display both base64 and the uri  i get from picker ? i just want to display the image when i get base64 and uri, I've already tried setting `base64:true` and that works but just want to i can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way to show the image like

```
<Image source={{uri: 'data:image/....'}} style={styles.image} />
```